# WPF ContextMenu that supports Rich Text?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

Is there any code or 3rd party control out there that will allow me to show a ContextMenu in WPF, where the Header text is richly formatted (ie, contains different colors, font sizes, etc).

Comment: You don't need any 3rd party for that, you can achieve that with some 5 lines of XAML. What have you tried?

Comment: How can it be achieved with 5 lines of XAML? If I override the ControlTemplate of the MenuItem, I'd have to duplicate the entire template that WPF uses, plus add my own changes to it. Won't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize `MenuItem` as you want:

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item">
            <ListBoxItem.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                       FontStyle="Italic"
                                       Foreground="Green"
                                       Text="Some header" />
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBoxItem.ContextMenu>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

Also you can create a style for `TextBlock` which is inside of `MenuItem.Header`.

Answer (score 0):

WPF Popup control can serve such purposes:

```
<Popup Name="myPopup" IsOpen="True">
    <Label Name="myLabel" Content="Some Caption" 
          Background="Black" Foreground="White"/>
    <...other controls you like.../>
</Popup>
```

Comment: Yes, but then I'd get something that doesn't behave nor look-like a regular ContextMenu, which is what I want. I'd just like to change the text header area to be rich text, other than that, I want a regular ContextMenu.

Comment: there is nothing distinctly different than context menu.